# Extend Source prototype to have a memory object

Tags: javascript, screeps

I want to store some information about energy sources that I am harvesting. Ideally I would use `mySource.memory.taken` but Source does not have a memory property.

I could implement something like this:

```
Source.prototype.memory = function() {
    return Memory.sources[this.id];
}
```

But can I implement the same thing as a property like other game objects rather than a method? Or is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to implement [Getter/Setter interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters) using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Here is the complete solution based on the existing game code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Source.prototype, 'memory', {
    get: function() {
        if(_.isUndefined(Memory.sources)) {
            Memory.sources = {};
        }
        if(!_.isObject(Memory.sources)) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return Memory.sources[this.id] = Memory.sources[this.id] || {};
    },
    set: function(value) {
        if(_.isUndefined(Memory.sources)) {
            Memory.sources = {};
        }
        if(!_.isObject(Memory.sources)) {
            throw new Error('Could not set source memory');
        }
        Memory.sources[this.id] = value;
    }
});
```